# Debian Docker config file

Tags: linux, apache, docker, debian

I have run the image `eboraas/apache-php` with the following command:

```
docker run --name eboraas -d -p 80:80 -v /my/project/dir/:/var/www/html \
    -v /my/config:/etc/apache2  eboraas/apache-php
```

When I test this I get the server is not found. When I leave the second `-v` it works. But how can I change the destination of my apache2 config files then? Without writing them again. For example I want all my config files of the Docker apache in `/my/config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st option** is create your own image based on the original image eboraas/apache-php(you should create your own Dockerfile) and use COPY in your Dockerfile.

```
FROM eboraas/apache-php
COPY /my/config /etc/apache2
```

How it works: when you change your local apache config file you should rebuild image after that and restart container to apply changes.

**2nd option** is just use `docker cp` and run it after every change in your local apache config file:

```
docker cp /my/config eboraas:/etc/apache2/
```

You can also copy config file if you change it inside the container:

```
docker cp eboraas:/etc/apache2/ /my/config
```

More info https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/.

BTW. I will recommend you to use docker-compose because this command is long and not comfortable to use(https://docs.docker.com/compose/).